# Upload image directly to server without storing in local directory

Tags: android, image-uploading, image-capture

How can I store the images which is taken from camera, directly to the server without storing in local system file?

I have tried to work out below:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
  File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Application", "IMG_temp.jpg");
  System.gc();
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

But how can I upload the image without giving path of local directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full size image then you can't. to get a full size image from the camera `Activity` you have to pass the Uri for saving the image.

You can get a thumbnail Image without saving it to the SD card.
Take a look a this post I wrote on taking images using the camera `Activity`:

[Use Camera Activity to get full size and thumbnail Image](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=590)